# Biasing element in another element in the scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll

Need header animation like this http://www.studio-neko.fr/ to my picture (height 100vh) placed in the top of the display device. How to implement this? Is someone an idea? Thank you.

Comment: Dmytro, what do you think about my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could see by inspecting its code (by clicking F12 at Chrome), that site is using GSAP Library (TweenMax.min.js)

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.4/TweenMax.min.js

if you open https://cdnjs.com/ and look for TweenMax you'll find the following description:

> Think of GSAP as the Swiss Army Knife of animation...but better. It
>   animates anything JavaScript can touch (CSS properties, canvas library
>   objects, SVG, generic objects, whatever) and it solves lots of browser
>   inconsistencies, all with blazing speed (up to 20x faster than
>   jQuery). See http://greensock.com/why-gsap/ for details. Other
>   libraries like jQuery, Velocity, Transit, and Zepto only tween CSS
>   properties. Plus, their sequencing abilities and runtime controls pale
>   by comparison. Simply put, GSAP is the most flexible high-performance
>   animation library on the planet. And unlike monolithic frameworks like
>   Famo.us or Angular that dictate how you structure your apps, GSAP
>   simply owns the animation layer; sprinkle it wherever you want. GSAP
>   stands for the GreenSock Animation Platform. There's a jQuery plugin
>   that hijacks the native jQuery.animate() method so that animations
>   perform much better and additional properties can be tweened, like
>   colors, transforms (2D and 3D), boxShadow, borderRadius, clip, and
>   lots more. GSAP has no dependencies on jQuery or other libraries. See
>   http://greensock.com/gsap/ for details.

Also, there are other js files that site is using, but that's probably the one responsible for those animations

I hope this helps.